# Org Reveal : Tabular fragments

Tags: org-mode, org-table, org-reveal

I'm using [org-reveal](https://github.com/yjwen/org-reveal/blob/master/Readme.org) to make a presentation.

I want to have elements in tabular form appear sequentially but in column-major order.

I know you can put `:frag` property-markers for gradual appearance.  But I don't know how to do that inside tables.

Maybe tables are not the way to do this???

My basic question is how to make things appear  (reveal!) in reveal in the general case:

- arbitrary order
- 2-d grid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  the following code as a starting point:

```
| @@html: <div class="fragment" data-fragment-index="0"> A  </div>@@ | @@html: <div class="fragment" data-fragment-index="3"> B  </div>@@ |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------+---|
| @@html: <div class="fragment" data-fragment-index="1"> C  </div>@@ | @@html: <div class="fragment" data-fragment-index="2"> D  </div>@@ |
```

Please notice the data-fragment-index property that give the order of appearance (first 0, then 1...). Also, the fragment class has several variants that you can find in the doc: https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/#fragments

Comment: Tnx — works! But is rather verbose. My [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/55722/5223) below tries to improve it some... (Of course the verbosity can only be improved by a feature-add to org-reveal I guess)

Comment: I also changed div to span

Answer (score 2):

For those who find this, heres a slightly less verbose approach to @Lgen 's [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/55700/5223)
 using a macro `a` (for appear).  Though I must confess to hardly knowing the ins and outs of macros in org

```
#+MACRO:  a @@html: <span class="fragment" data-fragment-index="$2">$1</span>@@
* Column Major
| {{{a(Hello,0)}}} | {{{a(yes,1)}}}   |
| {{{a(there,0)}}} | {{{a(no,1)}}}    |
```

Comment: Both span and macro are nice improvements to the initial version !