# orgmode - define multiple line code as macro

Tags: org-mode

How can I convert below code into a macro?

```
#+REVEAL_HTML: <div class="absolute" style="left:60%;top:0%">
[[./sample.png]]
#+REVEAL_HTML: </div>
```

I try it as below but doesn't work:

```
#+MACRO: mymacro #+REVEAL_HTML:<div class="absolute" style="left:60%;top:0%">$3#+REVEAL_HTML: </div>
```

Call it as:

```
{{{mymacro(50%,50%,[[./sample.png]])}}}
```

Comment: I don't use REVEAL so cannot answer directly. However, for HTML export, say, you can use inline directives, as in @@html:<div ...>@@text etc. You can therefore put these in the macro instead of the #+ directives.

Comment: See [Define org mode macro with line breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22132603/define-org-mode-macro-with-line-breaks)

Comment: Does [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/55361/5223) help?