# Org-Reveal: Fragmented list with source blocks

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-reveal

I'm preparing a talk in `org-reveal`. I'm using a construct like this on several slides:

```
- Bulletpoint A
#+begin_src
Example code for A
#+end_src
- Bulletpoint B
#+begin_src
Example code for B
#+end_src
```

I would like to fragment this such that first, only `Bulletpoint A` (with its code example) is visible and, after a click, `Bulletpoint B` with its code shows up.

I have tried various things:

- If I put a `#+ATTR_REVEAL: :frag t` on the line before `- Bulletpoint A`, then the list itself will be fragmented, but the code examples are both visible right from the start.
- From [this answer on fragmenting a table](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/55361/org-reveal-tabular-fragments) I've learned about `@@html: <div class="fragment"… @@`. However, I can't get this to work with source blocks. If I put the `@@html: … @@` before the `#+begin_src`, then `org-reveal` wraps the custom HTML in a `<p>…</p>`, which of course means that the source block is not wrapped inside the fragmenting `div` anymore. If I put the `@@html: … @@` inside the source block, it is output verbatim. I guess I would need to place the opening `<div>` right before the `<pre>` tag, but I don't see how to accomplish this in `org-reveal`.

So, two things would help me a lot:

- Is there any way of assigning a fragment index to a source block? I don't need fragmenting *inside* the source blocks.
- Is there a more comfortable way than manually writing the `@@html: … @@` (or macros with the same content) at every bullet point and every source block?

Comment: The problem might be that Org mode does not interpret this as a list of two elements. Try indenting (manually if necessary) the source blocks to the column under the `B` of `Bulletpoint`. Then put the cursor on the dash of the first item and say `M-: (org-element-at-point)`. It should say `(plain-list (:type unordered :begin 1 :end 139 ...)` - the values of `begin` and `end` are going to be different in your case, but *make sure that they encompass the whole list*. Use `C-x =` to check. Now try with `org-reveal` again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved this for me now is this. I first created these two macros to avoid the very verbose `@@html` syntax:

```
#+MACRO:  fb @@html: <div class="fragment" data-fragment-index="$1">@@
#+MACRO:  fe @@html: </div>@@
```

And then I manually wrap my bullet lists in these fragmenting `div`s:

```
{{{fb(1)}}}
   - Point A
#+begin_src 
Code for point A
#+end_src
{{{fe}}}
{{{fb(2)}}}
   - Point B
#+begin_src 
Code for point B
#+end_src
{{{fe}}}
{{{fb(3)}}}
   - Point C
#+begin_src bash
Code for point C
#+end_src
{{{fe}}}
```

This works rather predictably and does not depend on any indentations being correct.